# Django treating DateTimeField as both UTC and America/Chicago

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In my views.py I am both writing to and reading from a PostgreSQL table that has a DateTimeField.

When creating a new entry, the date field is populated in UTC time. When pulling the data from the database in views.py the UTC timestamp is being treated as though it is in the timezone "America/Chicago".

```
# settings.py
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

I've tried supplying varios timezone aware dates when creating the entry in the database but it always appears as UTC when viewing the database directly. When I pull the data back django is treating the UTC datetime as if the timezone were "America/Chicago"

```
# views.py
    CT = pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")
    UTC = pytz.timezone("UTC")
    # attempt_1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone(CT)
    # attempt_2 = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(CT)
    # attempt_3 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    attempt_4 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone(UTC)
    new_entry = MyModel(date=attempt_4)
    new_entry.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was occuring because my DateTimeField is defined in models.py as follows:

`date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

When creating a new entry, the date field is populated in UTC time as expected based on the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add).

> `auto_now_add` will automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored.
>
> > If USE_TZ is True, this will be an aware datetime representing the current time in UTC. Note that now() will always return times in UTC regardless of the value of TIME_ZONE; you can use localtime() to get the time in the current time zone.
> >     is_aware(value)

I ended up resolving my issue by changing `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` in settings.py. Though based on the documentation it appears you can also change models.py and define date without `auto_now_add` like so:

`date=models.DateTimeField()`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's working exactly like it supposed to according to [Time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) Django documentation:

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

You should use django's timezone module for your dates.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```